# Pass function to data after group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr

The following function extracts a linear regression model from a dataset.

```
eqlabels <- function(data, x, y){
  m <- lm(x ~ y, data);
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b * italic(x) * "," ~~ italic(r) ^ 2 ~ "=" ~ r2, 
                   list(a = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 3),
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 3),
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 2)))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));
  return(eq)
}
```

We can see it working

```
s <- eqlabels(data = iris, x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width)
s

italic(y) == "6.53" + "-0.223" * italic(x) * "," ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ 
    "=" ~ "0.014"
```

Question is how do I use this function with dplyr to calculate the equation and r2 values not for one group, but for several groups. For example:

```
result <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% eqlabels(x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width)
```

This seems to work but it only produces one, rather than three sets of equations and r2.

```
  > result
    italic(y) == "6.53" + "-0.223" * italic(x) * "," ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ 
        "=" ~ "0.014"
```

?do seems to be a dplyr function for this but I can't get it to work...

```
result <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% do(eqlabels(x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width),.)
```

This expression halts the function...

Please note that I'm trying to avoid using ddply from the plyr package.
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to look at the broom and purrr packages.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Scriven. I have tried that. You are right that In this case it shouldn't be necessary to use the `iris$` however, the function breaks without it... Perhaps the function needs to be re-made to be able to handle the piper, or the 'group_by()', or both...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
result <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>%
                   summarise(labels = list(eqlabels(., x = .$Sepal.Length, y = .$Sepal.Width)))

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

     Species    labels
      (fctr)     (chr)
1     setosa <call[3]>
2 versicolor <call[3]>
3  virginica <call[3]>
```

If you want `dplyr` to work nicely with `group_by`, you need to pass it a `mutate`, `summarise` or `do`, rather than your own function. The output from your function is also not super nice - I've wrapped it in a list:

```
result$labels[[1]]
italic(y) == "6.53" + "-0.223" * italic(x) * "," ~ ~italic(r)^2 ~ 
    "=" ~ "0.014"
```

As the above comment mentions, you should use the `broom` package, it will make your life much easier.